# How can I show the shipping cost on checkout page. Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have a plugin that is calculating the shipping cost and it will add the shipping cost on the order view (checkout page).
[image]

When the customer select the shipping method, then the total cost will be updated. And I want to display the total shipping cost on the order view.

[image]

I want to display the shipping cost on the `delivery charge` row. Have any idea to get the shipping cost?

Thanks a lot.

---

**Solution:**
To get the total shipping cost:
`$total_shipping = WC()->cart->shipping_total;`

Answer (score -1):

You need to Enable shipping methods from the backend woocommerce setting

Woocommerce->Setting
Shipping tab

Add your shipping classes

Comment: Yes. I enabled the shipping methods already, and I am using the plugin to do the calculation of the shipping method(first pic - I modified the shipping method display before the billing information). And now, I only want to get back the shipping cost in real time, when I changed the shipping method drop down box value(PIC1). So, how do I only get back the shipping cost? thx~~